# Running kubectl proxy from same pod vs different pod on same node - what's the difference?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm experimenting with [this](https://buoyant.io/2017/04/06/a-service-mesh-for-kubernetes-part-viii-linkerd-as-an-ingress-controller/), and I'm noticing a difference in behavior that I'm having trouble understanding, namely between running `kubectl proxy` from within a pod vs running it in a different pod.

The sample configuration run `kubectl proxy` and the container that needs it* in the same pod on a daemonset, i.e.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
# ...
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
    # ...
    spec:
      containers:

      # this container needs kubectl proxy to be running:
      - name: l5d
        # ...

      # so, let's run it:
      - name: kube-proxy
        image: buoyantio/kubectl:v1.8.5
        args:
         - "proxy"
         - "-p"
         - "8001"
```

When doing this on my cluster, I get the expected behavior. However, I will run other services that also need `kubectl proxy`, so I figured I'd rationalize that into its own daemon set to ensure it's running on all nodes. I thus removed the `kube-proxy` container and deployed the following daemon set:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: kube-proxy
  labels:
    app: kube-proxy
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kube-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kube-proxy
        image: buoyantio/kubectl:v1.8.5
        args:
        - "proxy"
        - "-p"
        - "8001"
```

In other words, the same container configuration as previously, but now running in independent pods on each node instead of within the same pod. With this configuration "stuff doesn't work anymore"**.

I realize the solution (at least for now) is to just run the `kube-proxy` container in any pod that needs it, but I'd like to know *why* I need to. Why isn't just running it in a daemonset enough?

I've tried to find more information about running `kubectl proxy` like this, but my search results drown in results about running it to access a remote cluster from a local environment, i.e. not at all what I'm after.

---

I include these details not because I think they're relevant, but because they might be even though I'm convinced they're not:

*) a Linkerd ingress controller, but I think that's irrelevant

**) in this case, the "working" state is that the ingress controller complains that the destination is unknown because there's no matching ingress rule, while the "not working" state is a network timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> namely between running kubectl proxy from within a pod vs running it in a different pod.

Assuming your cluster has an software defined network, such as flannel or calico, a Pod has its own IP and all containers within a Pod share the same networking space. Thus:

```
containers:
- name: c0
  command: ["curl", "127.0.0.1:8001"]
- name: c1
  command: ["kubectl", "proxy", "-p", "8001"]
```

will work, whereas in a `DaemonSet`, they are by definition not in the same `Pod` and thus the hypothetical `c0` above would need to use the DaemonSet's Pod's IP to contact 8001. That story is made more complicated by the fact that `kubectl proxy` by default *only* listens on 127.0.0.1, so you would need to alter the DaemonSet's Pod's `kubectl proxy` to include `--address='0.0.0.0' --accept-hosts='.*'` to even permit such cross-Pod communication. I believe you also need to declare the `ports:` array in the DaemonSet configuration, since you are now exposing that port into the cluster, but I'd have to double-check whether `ports:` is merely polite, or is actually required.

Comment: Ah, that explains it, thanks. But that also means that running `kube proxy` containers in multiple pods on the same node will not be a problem, because they're not competing for ports, right?

Comment: Correct; TCP/IP listeners are always a combination of the IP and port, and since every Pod is supposed to have its own IP address, then there are no conflicts.